# Export dynamically sized array with Kartik GridView

Tags: gridview, dynamic, export, yii2

I want to export a dynamically sized array with the Kartik GridView export mechanism. My code looks like this:

```
<?php $gridColumns = [
                'fullname',
                [... more personal details ...],
                'addresses',
            ];
        // Renders a export dropdown menu
        echo ExportMenu::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => $gridColumns
        ]);
?>
```

`Addresses` is an array that contains a number of addresses that usually varies between 0 and 3. Is there a way to export them using the following system:
`fullname`, `[... more personal detail columns ...]`, `[address_1]`, `[address_2]`, `...`, `[address_n]`

I want to have the export all in one and also prefer not to limit the number of addresses.

Ideal would be a column selection like this:

```
[ ] fullname
[ ] ...
[ ] Address 1
[ ] Address 2
[ ] Address ...
[ ] Address n
```

Comment: and the problem is?..what are you looking for?

Comment: I am looking for a way to dynamically add those options. The array has multiple entries but not set how many.

Answer (score 0):

You need dinamically the key of the array and use them for build the $gridColumns contents. Somethings like this where $array is your array of values

```
  foreach($array as $value)
  {
      $gridColumns =  $gridColumns . "'" . key($array)."'";
  }
```

Adapt the sample to your needs..